# Josephson Junctions: Difference between X and X enclosed by box (☒), in circuit diagrams?

Tags: circuit-design, superconductors

In circuit diagrams, Josephson Junctions are sometimes given as an `X` and sometimes as an X with a box around it `☒`. What is the difference?

Comment: Personal preference of the creators? JJs are not common enough items to have their own "official" schematic symbol

Comment: What's wrong with giving them an "official" symbol?

Comment: You would quickly run out of symbols when you gave everything one. It only makes sense for the most common things, not for a device that the majority of EEs never saw and probably even heard of.

Comment: Is the X used for anything else though?

Comment: usually for "thing that is clear from the context what it is". I have seen JJs being depicted as two triangles pointing to each other too.

Comment: But can you give an example where it is not a JJ?

Comment: in circles its often a lightbulb or a resistive load. NC pins are sometimes marked with Xs. In research I often see special sensors as just a box with an X (though its probably meant more as a box with diagonal lines).

Comment: Does anyone use just a box with a J inside it? Like the way Galanometer is a G ?

Comment: @user1271772 Use any symbol you want, just make sure the target schematic reader understands what it is. You could place a blue circle inside a red hexagon, just as long as there is descriptive text that says "this is a Josephson Junction". I bet the references where you've seen an X *tell you* what the X means or make it obvious to infer from context. If you are writing an academic work, use the same symbol as the most relevant reference.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there actually is a difference for Josephson junctions:

[image]

Source: https://qudev.phys.ethz.ch/content/courses/ASC04_SCqubits_Review.pdf